# between date cakephp 3

Tags: date, between, cakephp-3.x

when I make a between a date and see the log this adds spaces

```
$campaigns = TableRegistry::get('Administrator.Campaigns');
    $campaignsActual= $campaigns->find('All')
   ->where('parent_id IS NULL AND '.date("Y-m-d").' BETWEEN start AND end')
```

but

`SELECT 
  Campaigns.id AS`Campaigns__id`, 
  Campaigns.name AS`Campaigns__name`, 
  Campaigns.description AS`Campaigns__description`, 
  Campaigns.start AS`Campaigns__start`, 
  Campaigns.end AS`Campaigns__end`, 
  Campaigns.status AS`Campaigns__status`, 
  Campaigns.parent_id AS`Campaigns__parent_id`, 
  Campaigns.lft AS`Campaigns__lft`, 
  Campaigns.rght AS`Campaigns__rght`, 
  Campaigns.created AS`Campaigns__created`, 
  Campaigns.modified AS`Campaigns__modified
`FROM 
  campaigns Campaigns 
WHERE 
  parent_id IS NULL 
  AND 2017 - 01 - 23 BETWEEN start 
  AND end`

The date **2017 - 01 - 23** generates spaces How to ensure that these spaces are not converted?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `->where('parent_id IS NULL AND "'.date("Y-m-d").'" BETWEEN start AND end')`

"'.date("Y-m-d").'"